# action upon selecting cell in segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using below code for getting the action done upon selecting the cell in segmented control to perform the segue and pass the information accordingly, but it is not performing as expect, it is not doing anything upon the cell being tapped.

below code is implemented through extension

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("hello1")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyWsPostCell
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            print("hello2")
            cell.section1 = section1list[indexPath.row]
            cell.commentbutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.commentbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(todetailview(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            break
        case 1:
            print("hello4")
            cell.section2 = section2list[indexPath.row]
            cell.commentbutton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.commentbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(todetailview(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            break

        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
```

function called

```
    @objc func todetailview(_ sender: AnyObject) {

              performSegue(withIdentifier: "myWtoDetail", sender: self)

          }


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            var vc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            vc.infopassed = infokey

     }
```

if anymore information is required, please let me know

Comment: Have you set the delegate to the tableView?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma yes I already did that, one segue is already being performed as required, it is about the second segue for which cell has to be tapped

Comment: Ok, first of all you are adding target to button in didSelectRow. That wont call the action method.

Comment: Is didSelectRow being called?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma how to make sure didSelectRow being called? sorry, I am learning swift

Comment: In your viewDidLoad, set tableView.delegate = self. This will call didSelectRow. And right now whatever code you have written in didSelectRow should actually go in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Also didSelectRow doesn't return a cell. Please check online for how to implement a tableView, carefully follow all the steps. Let the methods autoComplete. Dont write them yourself to avoid mistakes.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I went through some examples but couldn't resolve it for the segmented control, though got to learn more about tableviews, can you please assist me with some code for segmented control?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are tapping on `Button` not on your `cell`, possible that `didSelect` not being called because `Button` cover your `cell`. You can use closer.

> Your Table View Cell Class

```
class XYZ : UITableViewCell {

  var btn1:(()->())?

  //Create Action For Button 
  @IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
     btn1?()
   }
}
```

> In your tableView : cellForRowAt method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:.....

     cell.btn1 = {
            ()in
         // You can Perform your action here. No need to maintain any tag or index 

      }
    }
```

Comment: will this work with "
    @IBOutlet weak var celltap: UIView!" instead of UIButton?

Comment: No. You have to add tap Gesture to your view. Or please explain what exactly you want to perform.

Comment: yes, I need to add tap gesture to the cell, so that whenever the user tap on the cell apart from the buttons, it performs a certain segue along with a certain data is passed, please guide me how to add tap gesture

Comment: Can you please show me your design hierarchy or storybord screenshot. Remember if you are tapping on cell then no need to add any gesture you can use `didselect` method

Comment: And add your button target inside your `cellForRow`  instead of `didSelectRow`.

Comment: And add your button target inside your `cellForRow`  instead of `didSelectRow`.

Comment: I already used didselect normal tableview for tapping the cell, but not able to implement in segmented control , please assist for segmented control, if you want more code for that please let me. know